# Symfony FOSUser override resettingForm

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I can't accomplish the resettingFrom override. Whereas i did it for the registrationForm. Here's my relevant files :

services.yml:

```
    mycars_frontend.resetting.form.type:
        class: Mycars\Website\FrontendBundle\Form\Type\ResettingFormType
        arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: mycars_frontend_resetting }
```

resettingFormType.php :

```
namespace Mycars\Website\FrontendBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\ResettingFormType as AbstractType;

class ResettingFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder->add('City');
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'mycars_frontend_resetting';
    }
}
```

config.yml:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Mycars\Website\FrontendBundle\Entity\Customer
    registration:
        form:
            type: mycars_frontend_registration
    resetting:
        form:
            type: mycars_frontend_resetting
```

Customer.php

```
namespace Mycars\Website\FrontendBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Mycars\Website\FrontendBundle\Entity\Customer
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CustomerRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="Customer")
 */

class Customer extends BaseUser
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */

    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $Civilite;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $Firstname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $Lastname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $Phone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $Address1;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $Address2;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=5, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $Zipcode;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $City;
```

I have no errors, just the normal profile edit Form..
Thanks !

Comment: Don't you have to use bundle inheritance as well? Could be totally wrong, just a thought off the top of my head.

Comment: I just update with the bundle inheritance ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your services defintion you have a typo:

```
mycars_frontend.resetting.form.type:
```

but it should be:

```
mycars_frontend_resetting.form.type:
```

I replaced a dot (.) with an underscore (_) between "frontend" and "resetting".

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to override the ResettingController and specify the form you want to use.

Comment: Ok i have overrided the controller but i don't know how to specify the form i want to use, the controller is for validate and save data no ? Sry i'm new :/

Comment: This http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.html should be helpful.

Comment: Yes you did. But I see a little difference in ResettingFormType.php. You have "use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\ResettingFormType as AbstractType;" instead of "use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;". To include the FOSUser form, this should be enough:  `public function getParent()
    {
        return 'fos_user_registration';
    }`

Comment: I have errors when i fit to the doc... As i said my other override work (registrationType) erf